# Understanding double to int64_t conversion

Tags: c++, double

So I have two functions, one just casts from `double` to `int64_t`, the other calls `std::round`:

```
std::int64_t my_cast(double d)
{
  auto t = static_cast<std::int64_t>(d);
  return t;
}

std::int64_t my_round(double d)
{
  auto t = std::round(d);
  return t;
}
```

They work correctly: `cast(3.64)` = `3` and `round(3.64)` = `4`. But, when I look at the assembly, they seem to be doing the same thing. So am wondering how they get different results?

```
$ g++ -std=c++1y -c -O3 ./round.cpp -o ./round.o 
$ objdump -dS ./round.o
./round.o:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <_Z7my_castd>:
   0:   f2 48 0f 2c c0          cvttsd2si %xmm0,%rax
   5:   c3                      retq
   6:   66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nopw   %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
   d:   00 00 00

0000000000000010 <_Z8my_roundd>:
  10:   48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
  14:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  19 <_Z7my_castd+0x19> <========!!!
  19:   48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
  1d:   f2 48 0f 2c c0          cvttsd2si %xmm0,%rax
  22:   c3                      retq

Disassembly of section .text.startup:

0000000000000030 <_GLOBAL__sub_I__Z7my_castd>:
  30:   48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
  34:   bf 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%edi
  39:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  3e <_GLOBAL__sub_I__Z7my_castd+0xe>
  3e:   ba 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%edx
  43:   be 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%esi
  48:   bf 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%edi
  4d:   48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
  51:   e9 00 00 00 00          jmpq   56 <_Z8my_roundd+0x46>
```

I am not sure what the purpose of that `callq` on line `14` is for, but, even with that, `my_cast` and `my_round` seem to be just doing a `cvttsd2si` which, I believe is conversion with truncation.

However, the two functions, like I mentioned earlier, produce different (correct) values on the same input (say `3.64`)

What is happening?

Comment: Note that round(x) = trunc( x + 0.5). I suspect you haven't properly identified all the machine code here.

Comment: GCC 5.3.0 produces a call to `round` https://gcc.godbolt.org/ @Cheersandhth.-Alf that's only true for non-negative values

Comment: `callq  19` it's an unresolved-yet reference to `std::round`. It will be filled in when the object is linked.

Comment: @Cheers and hth. - Alf That is not correct - those operations are not equivalent. For example, try `0.499999975 + 0.5` or `-1.4f + 0.5` with your cast method. Then try passing `0.499999975` and `-1.4` to the rounding function(s).

Comment: @JesperJuhl: Yes, I just pointed the OP in a good direction, I wasn't proposing the full details of an implementation (like, add a sign check). Much more effort involved for the latter. ;-) But thanks anyway.

Comment: @Cheers and hth. - Alf i honestly don't think it's "a good direction" since your method will result in incorrect rounding in some cases.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: I'll have to guess at what you fail to see then. First note that the issue here was understanding machine code, not implementing round. The OP wondered how the two calls could result in the same essential machine code instruction. The correspondence between round and trunc is how. So that's the good direction, helping to *understand*. But the posted machine code was an incorrect interpretation of object code, so it was also irrelevant for the concrete case at hand. No answer here has yet delved into the implementation of `round`. It may use that instruction, or not. ;-)

Comment: @Cheers and hth. - Alf in that case I misunderstood your comments. Sorry about that and thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Assembly output is more useful (`g++ ... -S && cat round.s`):

```
...
_Z7my_castd:
.LFB225:
    .cfi_startproc
    cvttsd2siq  %xmm0, %rax
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
...
_Z8my_roundd:
.LFB226:
    .cfi_startproc
    subq    $8, %rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    call    round             <<< This is what callq 19 means
    addq    $8, %rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    cvttsd2siq  %xmm0, %rax
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

As you can see, `my_round` calls `std::round` and then executes `cvttsd2siq` instruction. This is because `std::round(double)` returns `double`, so its result still has to be converted to `int64_t`. And that is what `cvttsd2siq` is doing in both your functions.

Answer (score 18):

With g++ you can have a higher level view of what's happening using the `-fdump-tree-optimized` switch:

```
$ g++ -std=c++1y -c -O3 -fdump-tree-optimized ./round.cpp
```

That produces a `round.cpp.165t.optimized` file:

```
;; Function int64_t my_cast(double) (_Z7my_castd, funcdef_no=224, decl_uid=4743$

int64_t my_cast(double) (double d)
{
  long int t;

  <bb 2>:
  t_2 = (long int) d_1(D);
  return t_2;
}


;; Function int64_t my_round(double) (_Z8my_roundd, funcdef_no=225, decl_uid=47$

int64_t my_round(double) (double d)
{
  double t;
  int64_t _3;

  <bb 2>:
  t_2 = round (d_1(D));
  _3 = (int64_t) t_2;
  return _3;
}
```

Here the differences are quite clear (and the call to the `round` function glaring).

Comment: plus 1 for the `-fdump-tree-optimized` option. very useful.

Answer (score 13):

When dumping an object file with `objdump -d`, it is quite important to add the option `-r`, which commands the utility to also dump relocations:

```
$ objdump -dr round.o
...
0000000000000010 <_Z8my_roundd>:
  10:   48 83 ec 28             sub    $0x28,%rsp
  14:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  19 <_Z8my_roundd+0x9>
                        15: R_X86_64_PC32       _ZSt5roundd
  19:   48 83 c4 28             add    $0x28,%rsp
  1d:   f2 48 0f 2c c0          cvttsd2si %xmm0,%rax
```

Now, notice the new line that appeared. That's a relocation instruction embodied into the object file. It instructs the linker to add a distance between `_Z8my_roundd+0x9` and `_ZSt5roundd` to the value found at offset 15.

The `e8` at offset 14 is the operation code for relative call. The following 4 bytes must contain the IP-relative offset to the function being called (the IP at the moment of execution pointing to the next instruction). Because the compiler cannot know that distance, it leaves it filled with zeroes and inserts a relocation so that linker can fill it later.

When disassembling without the `-r` option, relocations are ignored, and that creates the illusion that the function `_Z8my_roundd` makes a call into the middle of itself.